# User configurable url permissions in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that adds an action with a global hotkey to JIRA. I can hard code the url for my own instance of JIRA into my extension, but I would like this url to be user configurable as other users will have different urls for their own JIRA instances.

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this than just giving my extension permission for all urls and checking in my background script to compare the current url to the one the user has chosen as a setting. Ideally my background/inject script would only run on the users chosen url. I looked at the [permissions api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) but can't figure it out.

My current manifest.json looks as follows, I have hard coded permission to my jira url, is there a way to make this permission user configurable?

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "contentSettings",
    "storage",
    "commands",
    "http://myjiraurl/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "matches": [
      "http://myjiraurl/*"
    ],
    "scripts": ["src/background/background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://myjiraurl/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/jquery.min.js",
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you do, in order to inject into arbitrary hosts, you *have* to have `http://*/` and `https://*/` in your permissions, preferably optional permissions. Your proposal - comparing the current url with the one in the settings - sounds very reasonable: Just compare the current url with the one in the setting and make a `chrome.permissions.request` if it matches, silently stop running your code if it fails.

I can think of one work-around to avoid that, but honestly it's not giving you much:

1. Use `http://*/` and `https://*/` as *optional* permissions (you should really really make them optional anyway).
2. Make the `chrome.permissions.request` call at the time the user is modifying the **options**.
3. In your background script, make a `chrome.permissions.contains` call for the current url and silently stop running your code if there's no permission.

The result of the above is that instead of comparing the current url to the one in the setting, it will compare the current url with whatever the extension has previously got permission for. I guess it simplifies the background script a bit (you don't have to get the url stored in the settings), but makes the options page code a bit more complicated.